# image don't show up with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-8, show

**berita.blade.php**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVOx3.png]

```
img src="{{ asset('/img/'. $berita->foto )}}" height="50" width="50" alt="" srcset=""
```

**BeritaController.php**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z32Sc.png]

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $af = $request->file('foto')->store('public');
    $ambilFoto = $af->getClientOriginalName();
    $cek_berita = Berita::where('judul_berita', $request->judul_berita)->count();

    if ($cek_berita == 0) {
        $berita = new Berita;
        $berita->jenis_berita = $request->jenis_berita;
        $berita->judul_berita = $request->judul_berita;
        $berita->isi_berita = $request->isi_berita;
        $berita->foto = $ambilFoto;

        $af->move(public_path() . '/img/', $ambilFoto);

        $berita->save();

        Alert::success('Berhasil Tambah Berita', 'Silahkan Periksa Kembali');
    } else {
        Alert::error('Judul Berita Sudah Ada', 'Silahkan coba lagi');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: First, can you please check in html what is the path of the image which equals {{ asset('/img/'. $berita->foto )}}.

Comment: try <img src="{{ asset('public/img/'. $berita->foto ) }}" height="50" width="50" alt="">

Comment: Hi, I think you are duplicating a slash, because asset() function already add a trailing slash, so your call should be  {{ asset('img/'. $berita->foto )}}

Comment: Other comment, just for saving a line of code. You don't need a counter in your loop because Laravel already has initialized one in $loop variable. Please checkout this docs to see any properties available https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable